# Handle click on Today in a DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I would like to handle the user click on the `Today` part of a `DateTimePicker`. I looked into the decompiled source code of the `System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker` looking for an event or method to override but could not find any.

I know I could handle the `ValueChanged` event and compare it to `DateTime.Today` but I specifically need to handle the click on the `Today` button at the bottom (see screenshot).

[image: DateTimePicker]

Is there a way to do that by using the standard control (or by inheriting it) or should I use/create a full custom control for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could calculate the rectangle of the today's row:

```
Rectangle todayRect = new Rectangle(dateTimePicker1.Left, dateTimePicker1.Bottom + 160, dateTimePicker1.Width, 20);
```

then it's possible to compare the current mouse position to that rectangle in the `CloseUp` event handler:

```
dateTimePicker1.CloseUp += (s, e) =>
   {
       Point p = Cursor.Position;
       if (todayRect.Contains(PointToClient(p)))
           Console.WriteLine("Today!");
   };
```